# Why has my ConnectionsStringCollection more entries than my connection-Strings section in app.config?

Tags: c#, app-config

In my C#-WinForms-application (.Net 3.5, VS2008) I read the App.Config using:

```
Configuration myConfig = 
  ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

App.config contains two connection strings in the connectionStrings-Section:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="db1" connectionString="connection1"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="db2" connectionString="connection2"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

(connection strings abreviated for readability)

But when I loop through the ConnectionStringsCollection I find that it has **three** entries instead of the expected **two**. The additional entry points to a database called "aspnetdb.mdf" on a local SqlExpress-Server. I can't remember adding this anywhere, I can't find it as a literal value in my project files. Watching the collection with the debugger I find that *my* connection strings have the *app.config* as source. The additional string has *null* as source, so I think .net conjurs it up from somewhere.

How can I get rid of this entry, or failing that how can I tell the configuration manager to only use the connection strings in the app.config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aspnetdb.mdf comes from the default connection strings collection, remove it by adding

```
<clear />
```

to the top of your  element.

Comment: <ConnectionStrings>
  <clear /><--place it here-->
  <add name="myCon1" ...
  <add name="myCon2" ...
</ConnectionStrings>

Answer (score 6):

Did you check `machine.config`?

(Found in `%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG` for 64bit use `Framework64`.)

Comment: Probably correct. Had the same issue when taking the first connection, but one of our team failed to run the code. He had an obscure oracle tool installed, that's connection string survived the deinstallation inside the machine config (what a surprise, since the Oracle installers are so well-crafted ;-)

Comment: This was correct, found the entry there. Thanks a lot. However, I went with Stephen Newmans answer: by adding the "clear" on top of my section I can make sure that the end user of my application only hats the connections from the app.config.